# How to count the colored number of cells in excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-office

I am interested in calculating the similar colored cells in excel. I tried using VB script, when ever i close the sheet the calculation is lost.

Any one can help me on this.

Comment: Read this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384

Comment: how about saving the workbook after calculation and putting the value in a cell?

Comment: This link worked for me. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere (possible source - http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/sum-count-cells-by-color.htm) I have found this code to help me:

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult

    lCol = rColor.Interior.Color


    If SUM = True Then
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
                vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell)
            End If
        Next rCell
    Else
        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.Interior.Color = lCol Then
                vResult = 1 + vResult
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If

    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

The function accepts colored cell and the range, where to look for cells with similar color. The function returns number of found cells according to the color. Optional parameter "SUM" can be avoided (honestly, I have not used it myself). You just type "=ColorFunction" into cell and populate it with desired parameters in parenthesis:

Example, =ColorFunction(C3, A1:Q114)